# Which View lifeCycle to use in an Ionic 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Which View lifeCycle to use in an Ionic 2 project? Angular2+ or Ionic2/3 lifeCycle

Comment: you can use either or a combination of both..both sets of lifecycles get called for the pages

Comment: So there is no difference between the two ?

Comment: Another question : Should  use the ngOnInit in all pages? or just wait for the ionviewdidenter?

Comment: ionic lifecylce is based on navcontroller.. angular lifecycle is based  on the components itself..`ngOninit` is called when the component is first loaded.. http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Comment: Ah now it's clear thank you

Comment: keep in mind If you have your own components inside a page (a page divided in components), the page lifecycle only will be called in the page component, not the nested components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both, but since you're using Ionic framework I think  it's better to use Ionic Lifecycle, which covers all scenarios.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/